# Getting ip location and OS

Tags: php, html, operating-system, location, ip

I was wondering how to get the ip location and also what OS the visitor is running.
Say for instance, I use a Mac so if I would visit this website it would say Mac OS.

So basically something like **[ipchicken.com](http://ipchicken.com)** has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the client's ip, use the global [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

To resolve the ip to a hostname you can use [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php):

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

---

For the user agent header, which will contain information about the OS and the browser which the client is using, the preferred way is to use the function [`get_browser()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php):

```
$clientInfo = get_browser(null, true);
var_dump($clientInfo);
```

... what will give you an array like:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a closer look into it soon :)

Answer (score 1):

The IP of the visitor is available in the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` field, the user agent string is available in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` field.

Please note that both information may or may not be correct, depending on whether the visitor uses an HTTP proxy or modifies the headers sent by the browser.

The `Name Address` can be obtained by a reverse DNS request.

To get information like the visitors' operating system or browser vendor, you can use the `get_browser()` function provided by PHP or a replacement (depending on the environment you run your code in, the `browscap.ini` file required by PHPs `get_browser()` function might be outdated or missing).